# AWS Amplify HOC Authenticator React does not pass authState property to wrapped component

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to use Amplify Authenticator to block access to my app while a user is not signed in.

```
 <Authenticator includeGreetings={true}>
            <Provider store={dataStore}>
                <Router history={hist}>
                    <MyView>
                    </MyView>
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        </Authenticator>
```

In my component MyView in the render method I am trying to do a simple auth check by :

```
if (this.props.authState !== 'signedIn') {
            return (<></>);
        }
```

But for some reason when checking the auth state in the if condition, it is undefined.

1. Why is the property undefined - I understood in the docs that it is being down flown to all child components.

   2. Is my approach correct? I saw by the docs that you can implement a method showComponent(theme) and the authenticator will only call it once user is in specific states
      but I need to set the right states for the authenticator when to call this method
      by 
      this._validAuthStates = ['signedIn'];

but I don't understand where to call that method, I don't have access to this in any place.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a specialist but I faced this issue and struggle with the doc the same way you seems to.

I stumble over a solution

In the index, I render my components that way

```
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Authenticator
          hide={[SignUp, SignIn, Greetings]}
      >
        <CustomGreetings/>
        <CustomSignUp/>
        <CustomSignIn/>
        <App/>
      </Authenticator>
    </Provider>
```

In my app component, I now have access to the `authState`. So I re-inject it in the other components:

```
return(
  <Router>
    <NavbarComponent/>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/dashboard">
        <DashboardContainer authState={this.props.authState}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/admin">
        <AdminComponent authState={this.props.authState}/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

I don't know if it is THE solution but well, for me it works

Comment: Hmm, perhaps as in your solution versus mine, I need to have another component wrapping my <Router> component to handle the authState as it is passed only to the wrapping component, perhaps I must have an <App> component as in your example or something similar.
Thanks !

Comment: I am trying something else. I will try to use only Auth methods and not the authenticator. I think, it might be easier